# Split data if there are more than 2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am retrieving the below data

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║ group_concat ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  2 ║ a            ║
║  3 ║ a,a          ║
║  4 ║ a,a,a        ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

on my front-end table, I would like to display like below

```
╔════╦══════════════╦
║ id ║ group_concat ║
╠════╬══════════════╬
║  2 ║ a            ║
║  3 ║ a            ║
║    ║ a            ║
║  4 ║ a            ║
║    ║ a            ║
║    ║ a            ║
╚════╩══════════════╩
```

here is what I have tried. but doesn't seem right

```
var fields = data.split(',');
console.log(fields[0]);
return data;
```

any suggestions? thank you in advance

Comment: What does your `data` object look like? Like in javascript not the diagram

Comment: `data.replace(/,/g, "<br />")`

Comment: Sorry, what is your question exactly? could you all-berate on what `Split data if there are more than 2 in javascript` means?.

Comment: Nice diagram ! Keep it... what's missing is the data structure format (json,object...) !

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @Andreas Thank you so much! that is exactly what I want!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: https://jsfiddle.net/uboxesj6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an actual html table, you could do something like this:

```js
// sample data
const data = [
  'a', 'b,b', 'c,c,c'
];

// get the <table> element
const table = document.querySelector('table');

// convert each item in data to an array, e.g.
// data = [ ['a'], ['b', 'b'], ['c','c','c']  ]
const asArrays = data.map(item => item.split(','));

// convenience function for appending the values to the table
const appendRow = (value, index) => {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.innerHTML = `<td>${index}</td><td>${value}</td>`
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

// map over the array of arrays
asArrays.forEach(
  (items, index) => ( // index is of the outer array
    items.forEach( // iterate over the inner array
      // omit the outer index unless it's the first item for that index
      (x, i) => appendRow(x, i === 0 ? index : '')
    )
  )
);
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: If you return a string from `appendRow()` (which then should be renamed) and replace the `.forEach()` with `.map()` calls you can then use `.insertAdjacentHTML()` and only modify the DOM once instead of once per row. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/uboxesj6/

Comment: Fair enough. Intended more as an example of how to approach the problem than a production-ready solution. I've been using React so long my DOM js is a little rusty.